# "Cannot load such file" error when deploying Rails app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I'm using a [gem for gmail](https://github.com/jhk753/gmail-ruby-api) in my Rails app. My Gemfile contains:

```
gem 'gmail-api-ruby', :require => 'Gmail'
```

And in my controller, I initialize the gem with (using devise/omniauth to get the `refresh_token` from Google):

```
Gmail.client_id = ENV['CLIENT_ID']
Gmail.client_secret = ENV['CLIENT_SECRET']
Gmail.refresh_token = current_user.refresh_token
```

This works fine in development, but when I deploy to Heroku, I get the following error:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require': cannot load such file -- Gmail (LoadError)
```

I cannot figure out why. Should I be requiring the gem somewhere else in my app?

- Ruby 2.2.0
- Bundler: 1.8.5
- Rails: 4.2.0

Comment: When such issues happen, it's almost always the case that the changes to `Gemfile` & `Gemfile.lock` have not been committed and pushed up to heroku. Could you reconfirm that all the changes are committed and pushed up?

Comment: I just re-committed the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to Heroku, but I still continue to get this error. At this point, I'm debating starting a new Heroku project. I just can't figure out what is causing this.

Comment: Delete `Gemfile.lock`; Run `bundle install`; git commit; push; check again.

Comment: I deleted `Gemfile.lock` and ran `bundle install`, then committed and pushed to Heroku, but I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require` is case sensitive if the underlying filesystem is case sensitive (which it is on linux, which is what underpins heroku)

Change  to `:require => 'gmail'` instead of `Gmail` and you should be ok.

Comment: That was it. Wow, Thank you Frederick. I was going insane.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove useless `require` option from your `Gemfile` because `bundler` can load classes inside of this gem without specify `require` option in your case.

```
gem 'gmail-api-ruby', '~> 0.0.10'
```

and run `bundle install`.

FYI: read section about `require` option [here](http://bundler.io/gemfile.html).

Comment: If I remove the the `:require => 'gmail'` part, I get an "uninitialized constant: Gmail" error in the controller where I use it. The gem name and the class file within the gem are different. As I understand it, that is why I need to use the require statement in the Gemfile.