# LoadError: cannot load such file -- Base64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

I've just deployed an application to Heroku, but I keep getting an error message that it cannot find Base64. Why would this be? What am I doing incorrectly?

```
(master) $ git push staging master
Counting objects: 1278, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (366/366), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1278/1278), 152.61 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 1278 (delta 985), reused 1173 (delta 891)
[trim]
remote:        Could not detect rake tasks
remote:        ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app with no environment variables present
remote:        and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        LoadError: cannot load such file -- Base64
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/myob-api-0.0.4/lib/myob/api/client.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/myob-api-0.0.4/lib/myob/api.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `rescue in block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/Rakefile:4:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_d648ede1219e96df07f2f2f514c64e7d/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `load'
remote:        vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `<main>'
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        Injecting plugin 'rails_log_stdout'
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        Injecting plugin 'rails3_serve_static_assets'
remote: 
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        Add 'rails_12factor' gem to your Gemfile to skip plugin injection
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web, worker
remote:        Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 35.3MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v611
remote:        [app] deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote:  !   Cedar-10 will reach end-of-life on November 4th, 2015.
remote:  !   Upgrade to Cedar-14 at your earliest convenience.
remote:  !   For more information, check out the following Dev Center article:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-14-migration
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To git@heroku.com:app].git
   7ce6443..acf1899  master -> master
```

Comment: You can try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422629/could-not-detect-rake-tasks/21482089#21482089

Comment: I wouldn't fixate on the Base64 exception. I'd fixate on the error prior to the crash. It's providing very specific advice "Ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app with no environment variables present and using the production group of your Gemfile." Have you tried this?

Comment: I can successfully run that on my development environment without any issues

Comment: How are you requiring base64? Maybe it's a case-sensitivity issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056423/cannot-load-such-file-error-when-deploying-rails-app-to-heroku

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the MYOB-API gem had a typo. `Base64` is not `base64`